# How to Turn Multiple Union Statements into a Single Row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How would I turn this query into a single row with different column names.

```
 Select count(distinct accountid) as x
 from table1
 where active = 1
 and expiredate >= GetDate()
 and acceptedon is not null
 union
 Select count(distinct accountid) as x
 from table1
 where active = 1
 and expiredate <= GetDate()
 and acceptedon is not null
```

I get

```
x

5

4
```

I would like

```
x    y

5    4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want simple *conditional* aggregation :

```
Select count(distinct case when expiredate >= GetDate() then accountid end) as x,
       count(distinct case when expiredate <= GetDate() then accountid end) as y
from table1
where active = 1 and acceptedon is not null;
```

Comment: @Arulkumar. . .  absolutely not.